# Excel load the previous record allocated for the given cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

Good afternoon,

I am wondering how to use i.e. the match function for the previous value allocated for the given record. In the image below I have got the "Matt" string in one column and the different address in another column.

[image]

I want to use sth like PREVIOUS MATCH function, when it's possible.

I found some possible solutions here:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html

and regarding this incorporated the formula into my situation.

```
 =INDEX($D$3:$D$9,SMALL(IF($D$8=$G$3:$G$9,ROW($A$2:$G$9)-ROW($G$3)+1),2))
```

I am getting #NUM instead.

[image]

Nevertheless of my error the formula regards to 1st, 2nd match and eventually the last one. I need something similar for the previous record.

Only what I could find so far is:

https://exceljet.net/keyboard-shortcuts/find-previous-match

but they're only the keyboard shortcuts.

I could also find the formula for first and last match:

https://exceljet.net/how-to-lookup-first-and-last-match

but not for the previous one.

I tried also:

```
  =INDEX(IF($D$1:$D$20="Matt",$G$1:$G$20),MAX(IF($D$1:$D$20="Matt",ROW($G$1:$G$20))))
```

but I am getting #VALUE this time

UPLOAD:

My last approaching was the closest.

I used this formula:

```
  =LOOKUP(2,1/($D$2:$D$14=$D$8),$H$2:$H$14)
```

based on the solution from here:

https://trumpexcel.com/find-last-occurrence/

and it works, but brings me the last record instead of previous(preultimate) one.

How can I do this?

Comment: As far as I am concerned my list 1 will be the "Surveyor" list and list2 the "Address"? . The link which you sent me, doesn't explain it enough for me I am afraid.

Comment: =lookup(2,1/D3:D20 = MATCHVALUE), H3:H20)

Comment: at this moment this is the S6 cell

Comment: Then S6 = Lookup(2,1/($B$1:$B5=B6),($D$1:$D5)) .. Column B is Surveyor and Column D is Address. So Result should be "63 Corrie Road" .. Match found in B5 result in D5 .. Copy down / up the formula for the rest of the column... Note the combination of fixed and relative referencing

Comment: The formula works. Unfortunately this is not what I meant. I would like to get the previous (or preultimate) address from the list instead of the surveyor name. How can I do this?

Comment: If you look at my table. I am expecting the value from H6, which is the penultimate address assigned for Matt.

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/find-last-occurrence/
it's something like here but not the last occurrence but the penultimate one

Comment: =LOOKUP(2,1/($D$2:$D$14=$D$8),$H$2:$H$14) - this formula could work, if it would point the penultimate address from the list instead of the last one.

Comment: This exactly what I've done and it gives me the last address record instead of the penultimate one. I tried also: 
=LOOKUP((2,1/($D$2:$D$14=$D$8),$H$2:$H$14)-1) but it's too many arguments in this formula - Excel says

Comment: I did, but now I am getting #VALUE instead

Answer (score 0):

Use the array formula:

```
=INDEX(D3:D9,LARGE(--(B3:B9="Matt")*ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A" & ROWS(B3:B9))),IF(COUNTIF(B3:B9,"Matt")>1,2,1)))
```

Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. 
I don't know which cell(s) you want to use this formula. So, please with absolution/relative references in the formula to suit your need.